# c# mongo sort and sort (set by set)

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am trying to do different sort algorithm i called set by set sort. 
Here what i want to, we have "Posts" collection: "Bob" has 4 posts and "Jamie" has 3 posts.

**Problem**

In mongo i tried to group users then sort posts but there is no $second operator or $third, i have only one $first operator and that is give me first set of posts. Can't get the second, third, fourth sets etc..

```
var group = new BsonDocument {
  { "_id", "$UserId" },
  { "_document", new BsonDocument { { "$first", "$$ROOT" } } }
};

// code ...
```

This is give me just the first documents:

```
> [{ "UserId": "5b0154f3a614fbbb8a10fad0", "Title": "Bob Post 4", "DateTime": 2018-05-20 13:58:59.130, "Status": 0}, 
 { "UserId": "5b0154f3a614fbbb8a10fad1", "Title": "Jamie Post 3", "DateTime": 2018-05-20 13:57:59.130, "Status": 0}]
```

**Expected**

Below request and response showing my set by set sort example expected results. Grouping posts by user and sorting newest documents by datetime. Every new request to server with offset and limit i am expecting newest documents grouped by user and sorted by date time.

1. request get latest posts of users.
2. request get the before latest posts of users.
3. request get the before before latest posts of users.

*1. Request and response (get latest posts of users):*

```
> getPosts(offset: 0, limit: 2)
> [{ "UserId": "5b0154f3a614fbbb8a10fad0", "Title": "Bob Post 4", "DateTime": 2018-05-20 13:58:59.130, "Status": 0}, 
 { "UserId": "5b0154f3a614fbbb8a10fad1", "Title": "Jamie Post 3", "DateTime": 2018-05-20 13:57:59.130, "Status": 0}]
```

*2. Request and response (get the before latest posts of users):*

```
> getPosts(offset: 2, limit: 2)
> [{ "UserId": "5b0154f3a614fbbb8a10fad0", "Title": "Bob Post 3", "DateTime": 2018-05-20 12:58:59.130, "Status": 0}, 
 { "UserId": "5b0154f3a614fbbb8a10fad1", "Title": "Jamie Post 2", "DateTime": 2018-05-20 11:57:59.130, "Status": 0}]
```

*3. Request and response (get the before before latest posts of users):*

```
> getPosts(offset: 4, limit: 2)
> [{ "UserId": "5b0154f3a614fbbb8a10fad0", "Title": "Bob Post 2", "DateTime": 2018-05-20 12:58:59.130, "Status": 0}, 
  { "UserId": "5b0154f3a614fbbb8a10fad1", "Title": "Jamie Post 1", "DateTime": 2018-05-19 11:57:59.130, "Status": 0}]
```

**Post collection(documents) :**

```
UserId: 5b0154f3a614fbbb8a10fad0
Title: Bob Post 1
DateTime: 2018-05-20 13:58:59.130
Status: 0

UserId: 5b0154f3a614fbbb8a10fad0
Title: Bob Post 2
DateTime: 2018-05-20 12:58:59.130
Status: 0

UserId: 5b0154f3a614fbbb8a10fad1
Title: Jamie Post 1
DateTime: 2018-05-20 13:57:59.130
Status: 0

UserId: 5b0154f3a614fbbb8a10fad1
Title: Jamie Post 2
DateTime: 2018-05-20 11:57:59.130
Status: 0

UserId: 5b0154f3a614fbbb8a10fad0
Title: Bob Post 3
DateTime: 2018-05-20 12:58:59.130
Status: 0

UserId: 5b0154f3a614fbbb8a10fad1
Title: Jamie Post 3
DateTime: 2018-05-19 11:57:59.130
Status: 0

UserId: 5b0154f3a614fbbb8a10fad0
Title: Bob Post 4
DateTime: 2018-05-18 12:58:59.130
Status: 0
```

**Code:**

```
public virtual async Task<IEnumerable<Post>> PagingAsync(int offset, int limit, double lat, double lon, double maxDistanceMeters, double minDistanceMeters, string city, string category, string requestingUserId)
   {
     var col = _context._database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("post");
     var dateSort = Builders<BsonDocument>.Sort.Descending(document => document["DateTime"]);
     var addRadar = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq(document => document["AddToRadar"], true);
     var approved = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq(document => document["Status"], PostStatus.Approved);
     var cityEq = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq(document => document["City"], city);
     var notEqualRequestedUserId = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Ne(document => document["UserId"], requestingUserId);

     if (city == "") {
       cityEq = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Empty;
     }

     var categoryEq = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq(document => document["CategoryId"], category);
     var group = new BsonDocument
     {
       { "_id", "$UserId" },
       { "_document", new BsonDocument { { "$first", "$$ROOT" } } }
     };

     ProjectionDefinition<BsonDocument> projection = new BsonDocument{{ "document", "$_document"}};

     List<BsonDocument> result;

     if (category == "")
       categoryEq = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Empty;

     if (requestingUserId == "") 
       notEqualRequestedUserId = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Empty;


     result = await col.Aggregate()
         .Match(approved)
         .Match(addRadar)
         .Match(categoryEq)
         .Match(cityEq)
         .Match(notEqualRequestedUserId)
         .Sort(dateSort)
         .Group(group)
         .Project(projection)
         .Skip(offset)
         .Limit(limit)
         .ToListAsync();

     return result.Select(x => BsonSerializer.Deserialize<Post>(x["document"].AsBsonDocument)).ToList();
   }
```

Comment: Really unclear what you are asking. Show actual documents and what you expect to happen instead.

Comment: I thought this is clear. Example request and response is what i expected and below of code is problem and the last code is document. I didn't understand what do you want to see else?

Comment: One document does not display a sort order. Sorting strings is not sorting documents. You think, I think. I think you don't have an answer. If you want one, then I advise putting some more effort into making a question clearer when you are given advice it is not.

Comment: @NeilLunn I have updated my question with more details.